# How to group by and count

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe is below

```
user_id
1236
5842
1236
```

My out

```
user_id  count
1236    2
5842    1
```

`result = df.groupby(['user_id']).count()`  not working

Comment: df['user_id'].value_counts()

Comment: `df.groupby('user_id')['user_id'].count()` or what @YOandBEN_W says

Comment: it's `.size()` not `.count()`: `df.groupby('user_id').size()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit

`df.groupby(['user_id']).agg({'user_id': 'count'})`

```
         user_id
user_id         
1236           2
5842           1
```